# How to fix the loop so it doesn't keep stopping with entries left in the file c++

Tags: c++, loops, linker

I realize this is my second posting on this same topic and I thank you all for your patience with my less than stellar attempt at getting this to work. It's been a couple days since I last posted and I'm still trying to figure out why the loop insists on terminating after it has read 15 of the entries in the input file.

My professor provides us with a linker that contains the main() function and the two files that are present in the parameter, a sequential access input file and a random access output file, hence the acronym-ed names in the header. I have gotten all other instances working and such but me and my instructor haven't been able to figure out what is going on and I could really use some more help and any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int DESC_SIZE = 37;

struct Item
{
int itemId;
char description[DESC_SIZE];
double cost, price;
};

int processFile(const char* saifFile, const char* raofFile)
{
fstream outFile, inFile;
Item Inventory;
int counter = 0;
int errorCode = 0;

inFile.open(saifFile, ios::in);
outFile.open(raofFile, ios::out | ios:: binary | ios::trunc);
if (!inFile.fail())
{
    cout << " Part ID  Part Cost  Part Price   Part Description" << endl;
    cout << " =======  =========  ==========   ================" << endl;
    inFile >> Inventory.itemId;
    if (!inFile.eof())
    {
    while (!inFile.eof() && counter <= 100 && errorCode == 0)
        {
            inFile >> Inventory.cost >> Inventory.price;
            inFile.getline(Inventory.description, DESC_SIZE);
            if (Inventory.itemId != counter)
                errorCode = -4;
            if (Inventory.cost < 0)
                errorCode = -5;
            if (Inventory.price < 0)
                errorCode = -6;
            cout << "      " << Inventory.itemId << "     " << setw(5) << Inventory.cost << "       " << setw(5) << Inventory.price <<" " << Inventory.description << endl;
            counter++;
            inFile >> Inventory.itemId;
        }
        if (!inFile.eof())
            errorCode = -3;
    }
    else
        errorCode = -2;
}
else
    errorCode = -1;
inFile.close();
switch (errorCode)
{
case -1:
    cout << "ERROR: Cannot open input and/or output file.\n";
    break;
case -2:
    cout << "ERROR: Empty input file.\n";
    break;
case -3:
    cout << "ERROR: More than 100 records in the input file.\n";
    break;
case -4:
    cout << "ERROR: Item id numbers out of sequence in the input file.\n";
    break;
case -5:
    cout << "ERROR: Found record with negative cost in input file.\n";
    break;
case -6:
    cout << "ERROR: Found record with negative price in input file.\n";
    break;
}
if (errorCode != 0)
    return errorCode;
return counter;
```

}

Comment: You have an error code for every stop condition possible and you ask why it stops. Why you won't check your own `errorCode`, or tell it? You can also use a step-by-step debugger and find it on your own. Since you don't provide input, with expected output, and actual output noone can help you. You need to be specific.

Comment: How are you determining that it stops when it reads 15 entries?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Probably through the `return counter` but it's my wild crystal ball telling me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that it's the following code that's causing the problem:

```
inFile >> Inventory.cost >> Inventory.price;
inFile.getline(Inventory.description, DESC_SIZE);
```

If there is a newline left after the input going into `Inventory.price`, it will disrupt the following `getline()` statement, as it stops when it reaches a newline character. You'll have to ignore it with `ignore()`:

```
inFile >> Inventory.cost >> Inventory.price;
inFile.ignore(); // <==
inFile.getline(Inventory.description, DESC_SIZE);
```

Comment: You are a freaking genius! Thank you so much! I can't believe I didn't see this sooner.@0x499602D2

Comment: Wow. I am jealous of your dry-run debugging skills =). I was considering a bug in the outside code or input file. But text IO is not my thing. Btw. why is this community answer?

Comment: @luk32 Thanks. And I just felt like making it one. `:)`